# $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] not giving real port when i am using proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I am connected with wifi router and i setup proxy connection in firefox for checking REMOTE_PORT Giving which port

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
```

I am using this for getting port of proxy which i am using.But its giving Random port.
I am using ip : 123.134.167.208 Port : 6675
And above code returning 53603 Port which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the proxy you're using is forwarding the data to another port, so that it would not use the same port for in/outbound connections

> Computer(firefox) <--> proxy on port 6657 <-portforwarding->
>   proxy on random port 53603 <--> your server with PHP CODE

Comment: Can i detect that port or detect that its proxy?

Comment: @KRUNALDOSHI You want to detect port 6657 which is impossible, think about the principles of using a proxy.